# Adams apportionment

Tags: core-language, algorithm

I am trying to program the Adams' apportionment algorithm.  I have a problem when the minimum position corresponds to a party which won no seats. When I run the code, it gives me a set like `{-1, 4, 6}`. I don't know how to deal with this. :/

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
quota = 14 {38, 49, 280}/367;
qa = Ceiling[quota];
seats = Total[qa] - 14;

xa[0] = quota;
xa[n_] := xa[n] =
  Ceiling[xa[n - 1]] - 
   Table[If[{i} == 
      FirstPosition[{38, 49, 280}/(xa[n - 1] - 1), 
       Min[{38, 49, 280}/(xa[n - 1] - 1)]],
     1,
     0],
    {i, Length[xa[0]]}]

rj = Table[xa[n], {n, 1, seats}];
rj[[seats]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my take on Adams' apportionment. It is a straightforward translation of the definition given [here](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-adams-method-of-apportionment).

```
popStates = {38, 49, 280};
popTotal = Total @ popStates;
seats = 14;
div = popTotal/seats;

quotas[d_Integer?NonNegative] := Ceiling[popStates/(div + d)]

Module[{n, apportion},
  n = 0;
  While[apportion = Total @ quotas[n++]; apportion > seats];
  quotas[n]]
```

> `{2, 2, 10}`

#### Update

The above work was done with the OP`s data, but I was uncomfortable about that, so I decided to work with [real historical data](http://ww2.gannon.edu/cetl/caulfield/census/1832Adams.xls)

```
popData = 
  <|"NY" -> 1918578, "PA" -> 1348072, "RI" -> 97194, "DE" -> 75432, "others" -> 8491724|>;
usPop = 11931000;
seats = 240;

With[{popStates = Values @ popData, div = Round[usPop/seats]},
  quotas[d_Integer?NonNegative] := Ceiling[popStates/(div + d)]]
```

Initial apportionment

```
quotas[0]
```

> `{39, 28, 2, 2, 171}`

which totals to 242. Now we apply Adam's algorithm.

```
Module[{n, trial}, 
  n = 0;
  While[trial = Total @ quotas[n++]; trial > seats];
  quotas[n]]
```

> `{39, 27, 2, 2, 170}`

which totals to 240, so all is well.

Comment: maybe we need a historian to answer this but I don't see why `d` should be an integer.

Comment: @george2079. It doesn't, but an integer will do the job. Maybe you would be happier with a fraction of `div`? You might experiment.

Comment: @george2079. As to history, I don't know how values for `d` were determined historically.

Comment: I'd guess even back then they would have done a secant iteration or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Adams' method,

```
Ceiling[Values@popData/x] /. 
     FindRoot[
       Total@Ceiling[(Values@popData)/x] == seats, {x, usPop/seats, usPop}]
```

> {39, 27, 2, 2, 170}

and Jefferson's..

```
Floor[(Values@popData/x)] /. 
     FindRoot[
       Total@Floor[(Values@popData)/x] == seats, {x, 1, usPop/seats}]
```

> {39, 27, 1, 1, 172}

Comment: Thanks a lot . I would appreciate if you can help me for the Lowdes, Webster, Dean, Hunttington-Hill apportionment . Sorry , i'm a beginner in programming :(